# Unable to locate package libqt4-dev on Docker

Tags: ruby, docker

My Docker started to give this message when I'm trying to build

```
Unable to locate package libqt4-dev
```

Comment: Which image do you use? Versions?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/777388/unable-to-locate-package-libqt4-core-and-libqt4-gui-on-ubuntu-16

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242818/cant-install-libqt4-dev-on-focal-package-not-available-despite-appearing-in